# crossbar.io container configuration, invalid attribute value 'component.python' for attribute 'type' in worker item

Tags: python

I try to configure a container worker by this config file:

```html
{
   "controller": {
   },  
   "workers": [
      {   
         "type": "router",
         "options": {
            "pythonpath": [".."]
         },  
         "realms": [
            {   
               "name": "realm1",
               "roles": [
                  {   
                     "name": "anonymous",
                     "permissions": [
                        {   
                           "uri": "*",
                           "publish": true,
                           "subscribe": true,
                           "call": true,
                           "register": true
                        }   
                     ]   
                  }   
               ]   
            }   
         ],  
         "transports": [
            {   
               "type": "web",
               "endpoint": {
                  "type": "tcp",
                  "port": 8080
               },  
               "paths": {
                  "/": {
                     "type": "static",
                     "directory": ".."
                  },  
                  "ws": {
                     "type": "websocket"
                  }   
               }   
            }   
         ]   
      },  
      {   
         "type": "component.python",
         "class": "write_file.write_file.WriteFile",
         "router": {
             "type": "websocket",
             "endpoint": {
                 "type": "tcp",
                 "host": "localhost",
                 "port": 8080
             },  
             "url": "ws://localhost:8080/ws",
             "realm": "realm1"
         },  
         "options": {
             "pythonpath": [".."]
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

end I get:

"Error: invalid attribute value 'component.python' for attribute 'type' in worker item"

According to [this](http://crossbar.io/docs/Container-Configuration), there should be a 'component.python' type of worker.

What is wrong with the config?

I'll appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I was not able to find an answer, neither in the documentation nor on the internet, I tried to figure out how to set up the requested configuration by analyzing the source code of the crossbar `checkconfig.py` module.

In the end I got my class working by using the configuration below as an additional worker:

```
{
    "type" : "container", 
    "options" : {
        "pythonpath" : ["../"]
     }, 
    "components" : [{
            "type" : "class", 
            "classname" : "my/python/class", 
            "realm" : "realm1", 
            "transport" : {
                "type" : "websocket", 
                "endpoint" : {
                    "type" : "tcp", 
                    "host" : "localhost", 
                    "port" : 8080
                 }, 
                "url" : "ws://localhost:8080/ws"
             }
         }]
 }
```

Is this configuration working for you?

Comment: Excelent! I've found only now, there is a similar config here: (http://crossbar.io/docs/Getting-started-with-Python)